# How to correctly put my activities in Tutorial´s Bottom Navigation?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am new to programming. I have 4 working activities with 4 xml layouts. I also copied this simple example fragment (I think I need 4 of those for my 4 activites) from a tutorial:

```
public class SelectFriends extends Fragment {


    public SelectFriends () {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_SelectFriends , container, false);
    }

}
```

This is the relevant part from MainActivity:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.navigation_item1:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace(R.id.container, SelectFriends).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_item2:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace(R.id.container, StartFood).commit();
                return true;
[...]

        }
        return false;
    }
```

I can start my activitie´s selectFriends.xml when I replace fragment_SelectFriends in `@Override public View onCreateView` with ID of selectFriends.xml . The problem is I don´t know where to put the corresponding Activity, so the selectFriends.xml shows up correctly with BottomNavigation but there is no interaction possible, of course. What is best practice? Internet is confusing me: am I understanding the use of fragments false? I don´t even understand why I should make fragments with BottomNavigation when the things I want to show in the different BottomNavigation displays are completely different from each other. Thank you

Comment: I've noticed that this is at least the third time that you've posted this same question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/53219136, https://stackoverflow.com/q/53234243). Firstly, please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue. Secondly, it seems that you might have a fundamental misunderstanding of the nature of Activities and Fragments.

Comment: Fragments do not have a one-to-one correspondence to Activities, and you do not need a separate `Activity` class for each `Fragment` class. A single `Activity` can host and manipulate multiple `Fragment`s, which seems to be what you're looking to do. When you say that you have "4 working activities with 4 xml layouts", it seems that you actually want four `Fragment`s hosted within a single `Activity`. If that's the case, you simply need to transact the pertinent `Fragment`s within that single `Activity`.

Comment: @Mike M. Thank you for replying, it seems you understood my issue. My question is how do I transact the pertinent Fragments within that single Activity? By putting all 4 Activities somewhere into public class SelectFriends extends Fragment? Isn´t it bad practice because of battery drain: Everytime the App is opened that big activity code must be loaded even when the user intented to use only a litte part (1 activity) of the App...

Comment: As @Mike M. stated above you need one Activity which will hold your 4 other fragmens. After your activity is created it will load the first fragment. Then if you press a button in the navigation the activity will replace the current fragment with another one and so on...

Comment: @Skemelio If I understand you right, I have to put the two pieces of code that I posted above into one big class, and the corresponding Activity where
"// Required empty public constructor" is falsely written. Then I do the same with the other 3 Activities: I write a new class "StartFood" into that one big class. Can you give me a short example please, if I am wrong? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let's start from your question:*

> How to correctly put my activities in Tutorial´s Bottom Navigation?

You will not put your activities in the Bottom Navigation.

You will have one `Activity` which will draw the layout of your screen. Secondly you will have a number of `Fragment`'s which will represent some parts of your screen.

How many `Fragment`'s? As many as the Bottom Navigation's options. 
Take the **Youtube app** as an example.

[image]

The whole screen is an `Activity`, Youtube's MainActivity. As you can see the **user pressed Subscriptions** **in the Bottom Navigation** so the MainActivity called a `SubscriptionsFragment` to draw the subscriptions part of the screen (all the layout except the ActionBar at the top and the Bottom Navigation at the bottom.

If a user selects Home at the Bottom Navigation then the `MainActivity` will replace the part of the screen where the `SubscriptionsFragment` draw its layout  with the `HomeFragment`'s layout. And the same thing will happen with the other options of Youtube's Bottom Navigation bar.

So to clarify. There is **only one activity** here. The `MainActivity`. **Not four**. This activity commands 4 fragments to draw the 4 main parts of its screen (the home part with `HomeFragment`, the trending part with `TrendingFragment`, the subscription part with `SubscriptionFragment` and finally the library part with `LibraryFragment`.

*From your last comment:*

> I have to put the two pieces of code that I posted above into one big
>   class?

No you don't have to. It is not necessary to create one file, such as MainActivity.java (where your `MainActivity` is defined), and then define the `Fragment`'s classes inside the same file.

You want to display 4 screens using a bottom navigation, right? Create a file for your activity and four separate files, one per `Fragment`.

*Example:*

Your first file, SelectFriends.java, where SelectFriends fragment is defined, as you've posted above...

```
public class SelectFriends extends Fragment {


    public SelectFriends () {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_SelectFriends , container, false);
    }

}
```

Three more separate files like this one, one per fragment.

And lastly your activity, again, as you've posted above.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      // ... some code here
    }

    @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.navigation_item1:
                    ..
                // Here the activity figured out that the first item of the bottom navigation
                // was clicked, so it calls the support fragment manager to display a fragment
                // inside the container view
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.container, SelectFriends).commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_item2:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.container, StartFood).commit();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Edit: Read the [Ultimate Guide to Bottom Navigation on Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/ultimate-guide-to-bottom-navigation-on-android-75e4efb8105f)

Comment: thank you for your vast reply. I understand everything you told me, it´s like I assumed before. I also read the tutorial you linked and many more. But where exactly do I put all my Activities that I already created before starting with all that BottomNavigation stuff? I already had like at least 4 activities each one longer than 400 lines (I even used model layer for best practice). So where exactly do I place all that code which includes lines like: public class RestaurantListActivity extends AppCompatActivity { OR FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);?

Comment: First of all instead of thank me it would be better if you would upvote the answer  if you found it useful or mark it as correct if that's the case.

Comment: Now to your question: You already 4 activities and you want to convert them into 4 fragments. So you need to move the activities code into the fragments. As the docs say

*If you're converting an existing Android application to use fragments, you might simply move code from your activity's callback methods into the respective callback methods of your fragment.*

Comment: I created: Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) { and put most of my code in it. Your answer was the most helpful to find the solution so I accepted it.